# Disabling Source file preview window in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2019.1.4 version. I am not able to figure out how to disable/hide the source file preview shown in red box below?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have apparently [CodeGlance](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275-codeglance) plugin installed. You can uninstall this plugin or disable the code map in plugin settings.